# MongoDB 3.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 appears not to read /etc/mongod.conf

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I need help finding what I messed up in a recent upgrade.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, I recently purged all mongod-org

```
# apt-get purge mongod-org
# apt-get autoremove
```

Then installed, via Mongo's instructions, (got the new key added the 3.2 source)

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get mongodb-org
```

Everything appear to install fine. So let's start it up:

```
# service mongod start
mongod start/running, process 18811
# ps -ef | grep 18811
#
```

In other words, doesn't start. Nothing written to mongod.log so let's try command line!

```
# mongod
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting :    pid=18816 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=as3001snllx
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.3
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: b326ba837cf6f49d65c2f85e1b70f6f31ece7937
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-03-03T09:46:42.104-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-03-03T09:46:42.145-0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-03-03T09:46:42.145-0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

AH HAH!  No /data/db directory!  BUT, I have /etc/mongod.conf supposedly pointing to "/var/lib/mongodb".

Here's /etc/mongod.conf

```
$ cat /etc/mongod.conf
storage:
  dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"
  engine: "wiredTiger"
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
  logAppend: true

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
```

So, maybe my upstart config isn't reading this config file, since /data/db is a default setting.  BUT, my /etc/init/mongod.conf has a directive to supposedly read /etc/mongod.conf.

My /etc/init/mongod.conf file

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongod.conf

# Recommended ulimit values for mongod or mongos
# See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings
#
limit fsize unlimited unlimited
limit cpu unlimited unlimited
limit as unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 64000 64000
limit rss unlimited unlimited
limit nproc 64000 64000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
  if [ ! -d /var/lib/mongodb ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
  fi
  if [ ! -d /var/log/mongodb ]; then
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb && chown mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
  fi
  touch /var/run/mongodb.pid
  chown $DAEMONUSER /var/run/mongodb.pid
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGOD="yes"
  CONF=/etc/mongod.conf
  DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
  DAEMONUSER=${DAEMONUSER:-mongodb}
  DAEMONGROUP=${DAEMONGROUP:-mongodb}

  if [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]; then . /etc/default/mongod; fi

  # Handle NUMA access to CPUs (SERVER-3574)
  # This verifies the existence of numactl as well as testing that the command works
  NUMACTL_ARGS="--interleave=all"
  if which numactl >/dev/null 2>/dev/null && numactl $NUMACTL_ARGS ls / >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
  then
    NUMACTL="$(which numactl) -- $NUMACTL_ARGS"
    DAEMON_OPTS=${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  else
    NUMACTL=""
    DAEMON_OPTS="-- "${DAEMON_OPTS:-"--config $CONF"}
  fi

  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGOD" = "xyes" ]
  then
    exec start-stop-daemon --start \
        --chuid $DAEMONUSER:$DAEMONGROUP \
        --pidfile /var/run/mongodb.pid \
        --make-pidfile \
        --exec $NUMACTL $DAEMON $DAEMON_OPTS --setParameter failIndexKeyTooLong=false
  fi
end script
```

SO, Let's try starting mongod from command line with --config /etc/init.d

```
# mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

This works.  BUT, I need this to work through upstart!  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I added some logging to the upstart script by adding:

```
script
  exec 2>>/dev/.initramfs/mongo-init.log
  set -x
  ...
```

This put out the following:

```
more /dev/.initramfs/mongo-init.log
+ ENABLE_MONGOD=yes
+ CONF=/etc/mongod.conf
+ DAEMON=/usr/bin/mongod
+ DAEMONUSER=mongodb
+ DAEMONGROUP=mongodb
+ [ -f /etc/default/mongod ]
+ . /etc/default/mongod
+ limit fsize unlimited unlimited
/proc/self/fd/9: 1: /etc/default/mongod: limit: not found
```

Looking at /etc/default/mongod, I had:

```
more mongod
limit fsize unlimited unlimited  # (file size)
limit cpu unlimited unlimited    # (cpu time)
limit as unlimited unlimited     # (virtual memory size)
limit nofile 64000 64000         # (open files)
limit nproc 64000 64000          # (processes/threads)
```

which was an attempt at tuning a previous version, which I guess is not supported any more.  I commented out everything (not wanting to throw it away yet) and the now the upstart works.

Hopefully this helps someone else with a similar problem